# back button with image adapter (baseadapter)

Tags: android, gridview, back-button

i hope i haven't messed up!  But i've created and app and have it just about done but when i hit the back button it closes the app. I now realize that i am only changing the view on my Main Activity instead of launching separate activities using intent.  the app has 3 buttons to load 3 different "views" (easy, medium, hard) each is filled with an array of images. i will post some code but not sure what is needed. should i override the back button to get back to the MainActivity view? not sure the best way to fix this. thanks

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btnEasy:

            creatArray();
            btnEasy.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //hides button on the second activity
            btnMed.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            btnHard.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            btnHome.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnReset.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnFloat.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            grid=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid);  //grid is @id of grid in MainActivity
            grid.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            EasyGridAdapter adapter = new EasyGridAdapter(MainActivity.this, randomPics, overlay); //have to add all images (arrays here)  references arrays above
            grid.setAdapter(adapter);



            break; 




public class EasyGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private int[] easyPics;
private int[] overlayPic; //used for overlay ...this is just created here

Context myContext;

String pos0,pos1, pos2, pos3, pos4, pos5, pos6, pos7, pos8;  //for scoring game




public class Holder
{
    RelativeLayout rlParent;  //main layout (custom_easy.xml)
    ImageView iv;  //for images (grid) main ones
    ImageView ol;  //for overlay
}


public EasyGridAdapter(Context myContext, int easyPics[], int overlayPic[]){
    //sets gridadapter to use pics , if had text under pic would need to add after int[] pics
    // name EasyGridAdapter is name ot the java class
    this.myContext = myContext;
    this.easyPics = easyPics;
    this.overlayPic = overlayPic;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return easyPics.length;

}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return easyPics[position]; //worked with just easypics
   // return position;

}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView (final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View grid = convertView;  //grid (not sure if this is the same) is @id of grid on activity main
    final Holder holder=new Holder();
    if (convertView == null){

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) myContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); //think inflates above public EasyGridAdapter
        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_easy, null);

    }

    //main view (i think inializing veiw)
    holder.rlParent = (RelativeLayout) grid.findViewById(R.id.customParent); //customeParent @id set on custom_easy.xml
    holder.iv = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.easyPics); //EasyPics is android id name of imageviewer in custom easy xml
    holder.ol = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.overlayPic);



    holder.iv.setImageResource(easyPics[position]); //easypics is the interger from above
    holder.rlParent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (position==0)
            {

    REMOVED TO SAVE SPACE...


    holder.ol.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        }
    });



    return grid;  //returns grid which is name of grid on activity_main.xml (with all stuff in it)



}

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, i found this and it seems to be working!  i hope this helps someone else.

but in my MainActivity.java i added the following code now when i hit the back button it will return to the main screen!

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(in);
   // finish();

}
```